# NET Directory Services throws Error when quering LDAP server (not AD related)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ldap, directoryservices

I'm using .NET 3.5 and have build a successful LDAP lookup Function to consult users'data on a Sun LDAP server.

But, there is one particular record (so far) that is failing when it's being looked up.

When the Findone method is called , i get an 'Year, Month and Day Parameters describe an un-representable DateTime' error.

[image: Error]

Now, looking at the record in particular with an LDAP browser, say Softerrra, i can see this particular record is missing data in a particular attribute (baLastupdate field).

This field is of a date/time kind so i understand i'm getting an error thrown because the NULL field is not interpreted correctly as a date/time field.
[image]

**My Question is**:how can i intercept this error so that it doesn't crash and thus if the field is blank, doesn't crash out on me.
I 'm not defining anywhere what fields the LDAP system will provide nor what type of fields there are.

I've got my LDAPconnection set up as follows

```
Public Class LDAPDirectorySearcher
Private Shared LDAPDirEntry As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
Private Shared LDAPDirSearcher As DirectorySearcher

Public Shared Function DirSearcherSetup() As DirectorySearcher
    Try
        LDAPDirEntry = New DirectoryEntry
        LDAPDirEntry.Path = "LDAP://aaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.com/ou=people"
        LDAPDirEntry.Username = "yyyyyyyyyyy"
        LDAPDirEntry.Password = "xxxxxx"
        LDAPDirEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.FastBind

        LDAPDirSearcher = New DirectorySearcher(LDAPDirEntry)
        LDAPDirSearcher.CacheResults = True

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return LDAPDirSearcher

End Function
```

There's nothing wrong with the authentication or the setup or so (it works for +100K other records) but when there is no data in this date/time field, it crashes somehow.I'ld like to overcome this NULL field.

Comment: If the attribute has `generalizedTime` syntax, then "null" values are not permitted by LDAP-compliant servers.

Comment: tnxs, i'm trying to see how i can intercept this error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PropertiesToLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload.aspx) property to choose which properties to retrieve in the search.  Note that if you later call the `GetDirectoryEntry` method on the `SearchResult`, it'll probably crash there, too.

You could also try the lower level [`System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.aspx) namespace.

Comment: that did the trick.. a bit more work to initiate but functional.  `Sub New()`
`LDAPDirSearcher = LDAPDirectorySearcher.DirSearcherSetup`
`LDAPDirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("C")`
`LDAPDirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Mail")`
`LDAPDirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")`
`LDAPDirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SN")`
`LDAPDirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("l")`
`End Sub`